# Is there any way to cimport cv2 in cython?

Tags: python, opencv, cython

I am trying to cimport cv2 in Cython Code.

`cimport cv2`

I have installed the Python OpenCV module and the Cython wrapper for OpenCV, but I'm unsure how to cimport the cv2 module in my Cython code.

To get the best performance, if not cimport, how should the cv2 C++ code be imported and run directly using Cython?

This is the error that I am getting

```
Error compiling Cython file:
'opencv/cv.pxd' not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't `cimport cv` because the Python binding of OpenCV isn't written in Cython.

If you *really* wanted you could re-wrap the C++ OpenCV interface in Cython. I don't recommend this because it's a lot of work and you'd probably lose their nice use of Numpy arrays in place of the C++ `cv::Mat`.

To be honest this calling OpenCV from Cython is not likely to be worthwhile. Most OpenCV functions operate on whole images at a time. Therefore the function call overhead is likely fairly small compared to the actual cost of the function. What Cython is good at it speeding up operations where you're indexing a lot of individual pixels, and you can definitely mix that kind of Cython code with calls to OpenCV.

But just `import` OpenCV normally.

Comment: for hand-written loops, I'd recommend numba over cython. numba uses LLVM to JIT decorated python functions. hand-written pixel-touching loops can run faster than generic numpy functions. numba can also do loop parallelization. -- and then there's cupy, numpy for cuda. I also heard of CLpy, which is numpy for opencl.

Comment: Numba's definitely another option. In the past I've found it a little opaque in the cases where it doesn't work but very impressive when it does work.

Comment: @DavidW I am also having the same experience. What do you both suggest for DeepLearning Preprocessing ? Should I use cython with numpy and do transformations or use direct cv2 functions?

Comment: Use the direct cv2 functions where they're available - you're unlikely to be able to beat them, and write them yourself if the function you need doesn't exist